# save user location to mongodb, nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have and understanding problem when i try to find the location of the user and save to mongodb in location field of the user that i log-in. 
For auth i m using passport. connect to nodejs and save data to mongodb and everything is working right. I can't understand what should i do to save the real time location in location field of the user in mongo. It s my first js/nodejs/databse app, and i know this shouldn't be so hard but i can't find what should i do.

i can't show you what i've tried because the only thing i've tried was to understand the principle.
this is my user schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now },
  loc: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: [Number]
  }
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I expect in mongodb user collection, in loc field to see real time coords of me when i log in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to get the location of a user that logs in to your app.

One of the possible approaches would be to ask for permission to get the location during the authentication process.

To achieve this you can use [GEOLOCATION API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) and validate first if it is supported by the browser, then request the coordinates from the user.

And then if the user agrees than you put the location into a second `POST` request that you send alongside the first one that is used to get the auth token.
For that, you will need to create a new API endpoint(this example is written in express):

```
app.post("/users/:id", async (req, res) {
   try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
      user.loc = req.body.LOCATION_DATA_THAT_YOU_SENT_FROM_THE_FRONTEND;
      user.save();
      } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
   }
```

And by the way, if you want `loc` to be an object then you should create another Mongoose schema and reference it from the UserSchema:

```
const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   smthing: String,
   coords: Number    
})

// in UserSchema
...
loc: {
   type: LocationSchema
}
```

Comment: the path /users/:id should be the route for?

Comment: this is an arbitrary example of a route. You can come up with any other route you like. The point is that you should send a post request to this route and update the user's location on every login if you want the data to be relevant.